# AngularJS tags doesn't work in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In my code i've a table which is populated by `ng-repeat` tag., and that's ok. By clicking a button, a row is added to this table by innerHTML. This new row should contain 2 cells:

- `select`
- `input-field` + a confirm `button`

I want to populate the `select` with `ng-option` tag, and this is not going to happend.
The angularJS tags (and whatever script or function i try to insert) grafted with innerHTML do not work.

`methods` is a JSON containing 3 payment methods (PayPal, Postepay, Skrill).

`payment_methods` contains the user payment methods (method + notes).

If i try to add the innerHTML code simply in the html page, it all works, so there's no bug in http requests or angularJS tags.

Any solution? Thanks.

```
$http.get('/api/v1/getUserPaymentMethods', {params: {"idUser": myService.get()}}).success(function (data) {
    $scope.payment_methods = data;
});

document.getElementById('insert-btn').onclick = function () {
        var table = document.getElementById('table');
        var row = table.insertRow(table.length);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

        cell1.innerHTML = 
            "<select ng-model=\"selectedMethod\" " +
                "ng-options=\"method.method for method in methods\">" +
                    "<option value=\"\" disabled selected>Method</option>" +
            "</select>";

        cell2.innerHTML = 
            "<div class=\"input-field\" style=\"display:inline-block; width: 87%\">" +
                "<input type=\"text\" ng-model=\"notes\" id=\"notes\">" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div style=\"display:inline-block; width: 10%\"> " +
                "<button id=\"confirm-btn\">done</button>" +
            "</div>";

        $http.get('/api/v1/getMethods').success(function (data) {
            $scope.methods = data;
        });
    }
}

document.getElementById('confirm-btn').onclick = function () {
    // save data
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th style="width: 30%;" data-field="id_payment_method">Method</th>
    <th data-field="notes">Notes</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="payment_method in payment_methods">
    <td>{{payment_method.id_payment_method}}</td>
    <td>{{payment_method.notes}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<div style="bottom: 50px; right: 50px;">
    <button id="insert-btn">add payment method</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should keep both the element on html  itself, for showing and hiding them you should use `ng-if="condition"` directive

Comment: I combined `ng-if` and `ng-click` directives and it works

Answer (score 0):

With Angular you don't have to build html manually, but do something like this:

```
<table id="table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th style="width: 30%;" data-field="id_payment_method">Method</th>
    <th data-field="notes">Notes</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="payment_method in payment_methods">
    <td>{{payment_method.id_payment_method}}</td>
    <td>{{payment_method.notes}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select ng-model="selectedMethod" ng-options="method.method for method in methods" >
         </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="notes" id="notes"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I want that row (the second `<tr>` you wrote) to be added by `onclick` function of `insert-btn`. I though of make that row `'hidden'` and then `'visible'` but there would be an annoying blank space.

Comment: @GioeleGentile use ng-show or ng-hide, e.g.:
<tr ng-show='insert' ng-init='insert = false;'>
    <td>
        <select ng-model="selectedMethod" ng-options="method.method for method in methods" >
         </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="notes" id="notes"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<input type='submit' ng-click='insert = !insert;' text='Insert'>